# css translateY and translation-origin

Tags: css, css-transitions

Can someone help create an animation with an image that starts of like a door is open on the left where the translation-origin-x is on the right side of the image and when you hover over it - it closes like a door. What I have doesn't quite work and the image disappears can someone perfect it for me here is a link to a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NL5Mn/) and if possible could you make it start with keyframes so when it loads that page starts the animation straight away instead of hover animation

here is my css:

```
body > section > header > #section-logo {
    -webkit-perspective:300px;
   -webkit-transform-style:preserve-3d
}
body > section > header > #section-logo img{
    margin-right:80px;
    -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 1s;        
    -webkit-transform-origin-x:100%;        
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(-45deg) translateX(0px) 

}
body > section > header > #section-logo:hover img {

    -webkit-transform:rotateY(-0deg)
}
```

and the Html:

```
    <section>
    <header>
        <div id="section-logo">
            <img id="" alt="" src="Images/shop_departments_large.png" width="163" height="155" />
        </div>
    </header>
</section>
```

Comment: [This](http://jsfiddle.net/NL5Mn/1/) works for me, but due to [hardware limitation](chrome://gpu) my Chrome 30 can not show the 3D effect, while Firefox can.

Comment: Thanks @Passerby do you know how to make it start with key animations for when the page loads

Comment: Like this: http://jsfiddle.net/NL5Mn/3/ ? (I changed 1 second to 5 second to make it significant).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPDATED** 
The door closes onetime on page load & remains closed.
Check this: http://jsfiddle.net/error007/NL5Mn/5/

```
@-webkit-keyframes swingd {
    0% { -webkit-transform: rotateY(-50deg); }
    100% { -webkit-transform: rotateY(0deg); }
    /*
    50% { -webkit-transform: rotateY(0deg); }
    100% { -webkit-transform: rotateY(-50deg); }
    */
}

#section-logo {
    -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -webkit-perspective:300px;
}
#section-logo img{
    margin-right:80px;
    -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 1s;        
    -webkit-transform-origin: 100% 0%; 
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(0deg);
    /*-webkit-animation: swingd 2s infinite ; */
    -webkit-animation: swingd 3s 1;
}

#section-logo:hover img {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(0deg);
}
```

Comment: Thanks that works well do you know how to create it in key animations for when the page loads

Comment: @KDM added animation. Have a look

Comment: Yeah thats partly what I want can you make it with key animations  so when the page loads it starts the animation of the image closing like a door

Comment: @KDM Check the new fiddle. THe door now closes one time on page load & remains closed.